Change default user on WSL
When I start my terminal, I am in my root user, I then have to use the command su to go to my username. Is there way to change this that will start my terminal in my username instead of root?

you can modify the root user's .bashrc or .profile file by adding:
exec su - john

It might not be the best solution, but it will solve your problem in WLS :)
